# How to prevent 'drush up' from deleting non native inodes in a sub-theme folder?

Tags: drush, updating

I installed the [Basic](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic) theme, ran `drush up`, updated this theme. Once done, the sub-theme folder I created was deleted.

Is there something to do to prevent Drush from deleting a directory?

Comment: Did you place the sub-theme folder inside the base theme folder? Updates will wipe out the old folder, replacing it with the updated folder. So if your sub-theme was placed inside the base theme folder, this will happen. It should be placed alongside the base theme folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sub-theme folder is inside the base theme folder, it will get wiped out when there is an update to the base theme, as drush will remove the contents of the theme folder and replace them with the new updated contents of the theme.

The solution is to move the sub-theme folder to be along-side the base theme folder, so it's a sibling, rather than a child.

Comment: Yes. Module updates sometimes remove files, if they are unecessary. If the old file is left in the system, depending on how the code is written, these files can be picked up, and cause errors. I had to work through one such error one time, though it wasn't a drush update, it was a manual update, and I just uploaded the new module code over top the old module code. This put all the correct files into the system, but of course the unnecessary file was left there, which caused me errors.